# Proving that $p$ is prime: can I use contraposition such as I did?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers

> Suppose that $p \geq 2$ is an integer with the following property: If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $p|mn,$ either $p|m$ or $p|n.$ Show that $p$ is prime.

Assume that $p$ is not prime. Then $p = xy,$ for some integers $x,y.$ Then, the statement "If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $p|mn,$ either $p|m$ or $p|n."$ is not necessarily valid, for it is possible that $x|m, x \nmid n$ and $y|n, y \nmid m,$ in which case $xy|nm,$ but $xy \nmid n$ and $xy \nmid m.$

Does this proof work? My instincts are telling me that it's lacking. But, I don't trust my instincts.

Comment: You said "...for it is possible..." but why is it possible? Is it possible if $p$ is prime?

Comment: Well, not if $p$ is prime, since $p$ would not then be a product of two integers. As to why it is possible, well, you can have two integers $x$ and $y$ that are relatively prime and two integers $n$ and $m$ which are relatively prime, where $x$ and $m$ share primes and $y$ and $y$ share primes such that $x|m$ and $y|n.$ It follows then that $xy|nm,$ but $xy \nmid m$ and $xy \nmid n.$ For example, $x = 6, y = 5.$ Considering $m = 12, n = 5,$ $xy = 30 |60,$ but $xy = 30 \nmid 12$ and $xy = 30 \nmid 5.$

Comment: But the proof is incomplete?

Comment: `Thus p cannot be composite`  should complete the proof. It looks good to me

Comment: I see. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Instead of saying "it is possible", I recommend literally writing down a specific counterexample to the statement "if $p\mid mn$ then $p\mid m$ or $p\mid n$". How about $m=x$ and $n=y$? By the way, the assumption that $p\ge2$ is not prime gives more than just a factorization $p=xy$: it gives such a factorization where $1<x<p$ and $1<y<p$, which is important in this proof.

Comment: No, you haven't proved your statement. Saying "it is possible that..." doesn't make the cut, and neither does giving a counterexample. You must give a full proof of what you say. Even what you wrote in your first comment above isn't complete because it could be $\;x=y\;$ , as it happens with composite number which are the square of a prime, say $\;4\;$ or $\;25\;$ .

Comment: @ganeshie8 But it isn't. A mathematical proof cannot be compeled with "it is possible", or "it could be that..." .

Comment: @DonAntonio I see the complexity... Is it  the wording? Does replacing "it is possible" with "there exist $x,y,m,n$ such that ... "  fix the proof?

Comment: OK square of a prime thing kills the proof haha

Comment: @ganeshie8 In these cases a direct example or case that brings up a straightforward contradiction (as the OP chose a proof by contradiction) must be given.

Comment: Ah yes picking $x,y\lt p$ avoids all the issues XD You're awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the following way, simpler in my opinion,  using your idea: suppose $\;p\;$ is not a prime, then $\;p=xy\;,\;\;1<x,y<p\;$.

But then $\;p\,\mid xy(=p)\;$, yet it can't be that $\;p\,\mid x\;$ or $\;p\,\mid y\; $ as both $\;x,\,y<p\;$...!